# Can't make Spring aspect lowest order

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm writing custom aspect handles annotation for method invocation time measurement. I'm not sure that no one will implement his custom aspect for the same annotation. But I want to be sure that my aspect will be the last in annotation handling order for the most accurate time measurement.
If I put two aspects in context with `@Order` specification by my own

```
@Component
@Order(HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Aspect
public class Aspect1{}

@Component
@Order(LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Aspect
public class Aspect2{}
```

it works well.

But if I specify @Order only above `Aspect2`, the order breaks. I can't be sure that any who wan't to handle the same annotation will implement `Ordered` interface or specify `@Order` annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're certain rules about AOP handling in spring. If you don't implement the `Ordered` interface or don't have `Order` annotation imply you don't care about the order and such aspects are put at the end of ordered aspects.

For example

Class1 has implemented `Ordered` with order 10

Class2 has `Order` annotation with value 2

Class3 and Class4 neither have `Order` annotation nor they implement `Ordered` interfaces. In this case, Class3 and Class 4 can be in any order.

For this example, if all Aspects satisfy the execution criteria then they will be called as `Class1 <- Class2 <- Class3 <- Class4` or `Class1 <- Class2 <- Class4 <- Class3`

So if you really want your annotation should be at the last, then you should not implement the `Ordered` interface and should not have `Order` annotation. But as said this can be problematic as well if other Aspect also satisfies the same execution criteria and they also have neither `Order` annotation nor that have implemented `Ordered` annotation.